# Error:failed to parse values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: could not find expected directive name

Tags: kubernetes-helm

i have this helm chart, with a `values.yaml` file that has the following conditionals in it:

```
%{ if department_tag != "" ~}
podAnnotations:
  dept_id: ${department_tag}
%{ endif ~}
```

When I try to run a `helm template` command, I get the error: `Error: failed to parse values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 64: could not find expected directive name`

Commenting itout allows me to run the `helm template` command.

How to I add this variable into a mock values file / or via the helm command line so I could the the rendered templates ?

Comment: Is this in some broader context?  The syntax you show isn't the Helm/Go-template `{{ if }}...{{ end }}` syntax and I wouldn't expect Helm to specifically recognize it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you, you're right. I dug through the pipeline applying this, and found that somewhere along the line, they used jinja2 to prep the chart :|
If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently a similar error that i fixed by having my jinja template file in a seperate file like values.j2 and keeping the original values.yaml:

```
├── chart
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── templates
│   ├── values.j2
│   └── values.yaml
```

make sure not to have jinja syntax on the values.yaml.

Hope this helps